# Stuck with a Magento override problem

Tags: overrides, upgrade, magento2-enterprise

Recently upgraded to Magento enterprise edition 2.3.5-p2, I have a problem that occurs with a specific module during compilation:

```
SummaTheme\Widgets\Block\Banners\Product
            Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface. Actual type: array; File:
```

I know how to solve this specific problem injecting the following dependency: **\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository**.

My biggest problem is that I have tried to override the Block in a custom module inside app/code but then when I execute magento setup:di:compile throws the error again.

I need to do it without touching directly the module files because it's inside a module on the **vendor** folder.

Anyone has any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Take a look here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312378/magento-2-3-5-incompatible-argument-type-errors-during-compilation

Comment: share the code of that Block file where error show?